# Does grass spread in the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently started a hermit chunk and managed to get a grass block from an enderman and obviously don't want to waste it. Searching the internet for an answer has been fruitless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**. Grass will spread from grass blocks to dirt in all biomes and all dimensions, including the nether

Answer (score 1):

It will as long as a **light source** such as a torch beside the grass is there to allow it to spread. (as of Java 1.16.5)